# FBO and Textures

Tags: opengl, glsl, fbo

I have attached two textures to an FBO. The first texture will be used to show a depth map. The second texture will show the object in a normal way.

If I do this, it works well and shows me the depth map.

```
GLuint atach0 = GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT;
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,fboBuffer);
  glDrawBuffers(1,&atach0);
  glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  glViewport(0.0,0.0,640,480);
  LProjection = glm::ortho(-10.0f,10.0f,-10.0f,10.0f,-500.0f,500.0f);
  LView = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0.0f,15.0f,0.000001f),glm::vec3(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f),glm::vec3(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f));
  LViewProjection = LProjection * LView;
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

  ...CUBE3D

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,0);

glUniform1i(uniforTEX,0);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_DEPTH_MAP);

  ...DRAW-DEPTH-MAP!

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0);
```

But if I do this, it only shows a white screen and the depth map is no longer visible.

```
GLuint atach0 = GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT;
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,fboBuffer);
  glDrawBuffers(1,&atach0);
  glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  glViewport(auxrecX,auxrecY,auxrcAn,auxrcAl);
  LProjection = glm::ortho(-10.0f,10.0f,-10.0f,10.0f,-500.0f,500.0f);
  LView = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0.0f,15.0f,0.000001f),glm::vec3(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f),glm::vec3(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f));
  LViewProjection = LProjection * LView;
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

  ...CUBE3D

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,0);

GLuint atach1 = GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0;
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,fboBuffer);
  glDrawBuffers(1,&atach1);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  glViewport(0,0,640,480);
  Projection = glm::perspective(45.0f,1.333333f,0.01f,1000.0f);
  View = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0.0f,0.0f,3.0),glm::vec3(0.0f,0.0f,-15.0f),glm::vec3(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f));
  ViewProjection = Projection * View;
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

  ...CUBE3D

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,0);   

glUniform1i(uniforTEX,0);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_DEPTH_MAP);

  ...DO NOT DRAW NOTHING

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0);
```

I need to do it in that order. Because the first "pass" is for the use of the depth map in a shadow map. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT` is not valid for [`glDrawBuffers`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawBuffers.xhtml). `glDrawBuffers` of buffers into which outputs from the fragment shader data will be written.

When you do

> ```
> GLuint atach0 = GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT;
> glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,fboBuffer);
> ```

then you'll get a `GL_INVALID_ENUM` error.

If you don't want to wirte to the depth map, then disable the depth test of use [`glDepthMask`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDepthMask.xhtml). The depth buffer attachment can't be switched on and off and it can't be uses somehow like a color buffer.

Further

> ```
> glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
> ```

will clear the depth buffer in any case.

I think there is a basic misunderstanding how the framebuffers for a shadow map have to be set up. You'll need a framebuffer for the shadow map only. This framebuffer has to have a depth buffer only.

You have to do mit somehow like this:

```cpp
GLuint fboShadow;      // framebuffer with depth buffer only (shadow map)
GLuint toShadowDepth;  // texture which is the depth buffer of `fboShadow`
```

```cpp
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboShadow);
GLuint atach0 = GL_NONE;
glDrawBuffers(1, &atach0);
glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glViewport(auxrecX, auxrecY, auxrcAn, auxrcAl);

// draw the shadow map to the depth buffer only

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glViewport(0, 0, 640, 480);

glUniform1i(uniforTEX, 0);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, toShadowDepth);

// draw the geometry to the default framebuffer by using the depth map
```

Comment: I'm going to try it. Thank you very much for your answer friend.